# why is a returning method from __call() returning array?

Tags: php, class

I have a class that uses __call():

```
public function __call($method, $args){
     $method = "_".$method;
     if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
        try {
            return $this->$method($args);
        }
        catch (Validation_exception $e) {
            $this->exceptions[] = $e->getMessage();
            return;
        }
     }
}
```

But that will return me an array even if I have a method that returns a string:

```
protected function _return_string(){
    return "string"; 
}
```

So if I do:
    echo $myclass->return_string();
    print_r( $myclass->return_string() );

It will output:
    Array()
    Array([0] => "string")

Why does it return an array??

Comment: [cannot reproduce](http://codepad.org/PdXOp95k)

Comment: Maybe you go some weird PHP preprocessor trying to correct your `:` that's not a semi-colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class myClass {
    protected function _return_string($arg){
        return is_array($arg) ? $arg[0] : $arg;
    }

    public function __call($method, $args){
        $method = "_".$method;
        if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
            try {
                return $this->$method($args); // $args passed as an array here
            }
            catch (Validation_exception $e) {
                $this->exceptions[] = $e->getMessage();
                return;
            }
         }
    }
}

$foo = new myClass();
echo $foo->__call('return_string','Hello'); // Prints "Hello" 
echo $foo->return_string(' World'); //Prints "World"
```

// output on screen "Hello World"

**Note:** return $this->$method($args) passed $args as an array.